# Using sed to replace character

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am leaning how to use awk and sed this week. I know this question might have been asked before but I am not sure what is wrong with my script. I have three files and I am using grep to search for the pattern gge0001x gge0001y gge0001z. x is in file1, y is in file 2, and z is in file3.   If anyone wants to see L2E[1-3].iva they are here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1112988408874c730cd4f3d313226ba4

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Performance Data"
sed -n '1,19p' L2E1.iva|cat > file1 #take lines 1-19 in L2E1 and take the 
# output into file1. The next two commands do the same thing
sed -n '1,19p' L2E2.iva|cat > file2
sed -n '1,19p' L2E3.iva|cat > file3
curveName=`grep "F" file1|sed "s/F/ /"`
# This will search for F in file 1, and then substitute F with a space 
curveName2=`grep "F" file2|sed "s/F/ /"`
curveName3=`grep "F" file3|sed "s/F/ /"`
echo "Curve Name" "$curveName $curveName2 $curveName3"
```

I want my output to be Curve Name gge0001x gge0001y gge0001z. But the output is this instead: 
Performance Data gge0006ze gge0006x

If I echo them out by themselves then it is fine, but once I echo all three on the same line the output gets skewed. Why does x show up last when it is first when I echo it and where did my y go to?

Comment: maybe you need `&&` when run multiple commands and also when your substitute characters, it would not save the changes to file, you know that, right?

Comment: I've tried that, it gives me the following: 
Performance Data
Curve Name gge0006x
./lab5.2: line 19: $'gge0006y\r': command not found

Comment: You have `\r` characters in your files.  Run dos2unix on  your input files.

Comment: Never pipe `grep` to `sed`.  Instead of `grep foo  | sed 'cmd'`, just do `sed '/foo/cmd'`

Comment: Instead of `sed 's/F/ /'`, you should use `sed 'y/F/ /'`, but instead of that you should use `tr F ' '`

Comment: Fix the typos in your script (e.g. curvename2 vs curveName2) then create a [mcve] demonstrating ONLY the problem you want to ask a question about. Most of the lines in your script are extraneous fluff that you don't need (and more importantly we don't need to wade through) to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A few tips at first:

> ```
> sed -n '1,19p' L2E1.iva|cat > file1
> ```

You can omit the `cat` an redirect the output of `sed` directly to the file:

```
sed -n '1,19p' L2E1.iva > file1
```

> ```
> curveName=`grep "F" file1|sed "s/F/ /"`
> ```

Use `$()` instead of backticks for process substitution:

```
curveName=$(grep "F" file1 | sed "s/F/ /")
```

> But the output is this instead: Performance Data gge0006ze gge0006x

The reason for *Performance Data* in your output is, that you `echo` it at the beginning of your script.

Moreover you've got a typo in the last `echo`: $curve**n**ame2 -> $curve**N**ame2, this is why your *y* is missing.

Did you double check your files for the right contents? That's the only reason i can imagine, why your *x* comes last and the *z* first.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I fixed the type with curveName2, but its still missing. I double checked all three of my files and they contain the x,y,z in order.

Comment: Did you run dos2unix on them as @WilliamPursell suggested? Chances are the `\r`s in your input file are causing your cursor to jump back to the start of the line so the next thing output is visually overwriting the preceding text.

Comment: @EdMorton did that and it fixed everything!

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps compress your script into one line

```
$ echo Curve name $(grep -Pohm1 '(?<=F ).*' L2E{1..3})

Curve name gge0006x gge0006y gge0006z
```

exercise is to search the options used in `grep`